# Using the same connection with Mojo::UserAgent

Tags: perl, mojolicious, lwp-useragent

I am trying to use NTLM authentication with Mojolicious::UserAgent, porting some code I got to work ok using LWP::UserAgent. I suspect that it fails because "this scheme authenticates connections, not requests" and therefore the network connection must be kept alive during multiple parts of the NTLM handshake. With LWP I do

```
 LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive => 1)
```

I reckon that Mojo::UserAgent is not using a single connection for subsequent requests, and therefore the handshake fails.

Is that so? and how do I prevent it? in other words how do I guarantee that a series of Mojolicious::UserAgent GETs and POSTs is done through the exact same connection?

Comment: The [M::UA doc says](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent#max_connections) it will by default keep 5 connections alive before starting to close them.